# Android Studio - Need help looping code every second

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio

I need a system that will execute this code every second. I've been looking for a while and still can't find any ways that work. I'm quite new to Java programming and programming for android so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Values n = new Values();

double num = n.getNum();
double adder = n.getAdder();
if(adder>=1) {
  num += (adder * 0.1);
}
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t.setText(num + "");
n.setNum(num);
```

Also, I'm importing values from a **Values** class that looks like this,

```
package com.example.durtle02.durtle02;

public class Values {
  double num;
  double cost = 30;
  double adder;

  public double getNum() {
    return num;
  }

  public void setNum(double num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  public double getCost() {
    return cost;
  }

  public void setCost(double cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
  }

  public double getAdder() {
    return adder;
  }

  public void setAdder(double adder) {
    this.adder = adder;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.durtle02.durtle02;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.sql.Time;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //making game values accessible
    final Values n = new Values();
    //Loading The button for adding
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double num = n.getNum();
            num++;
            TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            n.setNum(num);
            tt.setText(n.getNum() + "");
        }
    });
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double num = n.getNum();
            double cost = n.getCost();
            double adder = n.getAdder();
            if (num >= cost) {
                num -= cost;
                cost = cost * 1.35;
                adder++;
                cost = Math.round(cost);
                n.setNum(num);
                n.setCost(cost);
                n.setAdder(adder);
                TextView tl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                tl.setText(n.getCost() + "");
                TextView tk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                tk.setText(n.getAdder() + " Adders");
                TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tt.setText(n.getNum() + "");
                TextView tp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                tp.setText((n.getAdder() * 0.1) + "/s");
            }
        }
    });
   countDownTimer.start();
}

 // Do something each second in a time frame of 60 seconds.
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 100) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Values n = new Values();

        double num = n.getNum();
        double adder = n.getAdder();
        if(adder>=1) {
            num += (adder * 0.1);
        }
        num++;
        n.setNum(num);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        countDownTimer.start(); // restart again.
    }
};

        /*
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        Values n = new Values();

        double num = n.getNum();
        double adder = n.getAdder();
        if(adder>=1) {
            num += (adder * 0.1);
        }
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText(num + "");

        n.setNum(num);
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        */

    }
```

Comment: How about a simple loop and sleep solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), something like this:

```
// Do something each second in a time frame of 60 seconds.
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    // For every second, do something.
    doSomething();
  }

  public void onFinish() {
    countDownTimer.start(); // restart again.
  }
}.start();
```

Comment: I implemented the code in different places and it didn't seem to work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you put your to be executed code in `onTick` method?

Comment: Yes. It didn't seem to work. I also put in the MainActivity.java code in the main post. I've tried putting the code in there and in separate classes. Nothing has worked yet.

Comment: I think I haven't tell you that if you want to initialize the code you don't need to add `CountDownTimer.start()`. You need to call it when you ready to start the CountDownTimer. So, change `CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 100) {...
}.start();` to  `CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 100) {...
};`. Then call it in the end of `onCreate method` with `countDownTimer.start();`

Comment: didn't you forget the `()` as `start()` ?

Comment: Never mind I got it to work. Thanks. I had the start in the wrong place then I just had to rearrange some of my code.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is in the foreground, the following code will do.

```
Handler mHandler= new Handler()
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your stuff here, called every second
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

// start it with:
mHandler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: On "mHandler" I'm getting a "Cannot resolve symbol 'mHandler'"
And for "mHandler.post(runnable);" it's saying "unknown class 'runnable'"

Comment: I don't think this will work in about 1-second constraint. If you add some code to the `run method`, the time consumed will be: `time for code` + `1 second`.

Comment: The executing code is short, not a big deal. If the executing code is too much, the post delay time can be adjusted.